# 2003 joining domain "The specified network name is unavailable"

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain

I know theres a few topics for this when i used my google-fu but none of them seem to resolve the issue.

We had an '03 server act up the other day. The original issue was it wouldn't let us remote using domain creds. Everything seemed fine when we consoled to it. Could ping, Nslookup, whole nine yards. In the processes of bug fixing we undomained it, and when trying to redomain we get that error above.

Now i know this typically mean DNS issue but everything seems correct. I can ping DC by name. nslookup resolves correctly. When i go to domain it i have tried FQDN and regular. Both prompt user cred boxes.

I have removed the entry (03 server) from DNS and re added it. I have made sure this server has a reverse lookup in DNS.

I have made sure server, workstation, and browser services are started. I've tried about all the resolutions i've seen here.

Any ideas? The only thing i see is i can't get the Primary Suffix to populate on ipconfig /all. I have it listed as mydomain.local under computer name changes screen

```
 Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 03_server
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mydomain.local

Ethernet adapter mydomain.local:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Accelerated AMD PCNet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-A4-00-27
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.0.168
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.0.129
                                       10.1.0.130
```

Comment: Can you define 'acting up'? Is it possible that these issues are closely related - for example, were you trying to fix problems with domain authentication, GPO's etc? DNS wise, can you resolve/ping 'mydomain.local'?

Comment: The original issue was it wouldn't let us remote using domain creds. So domain auth issues. Same story as above everything seemed fine when we consoled to it. Could ping Nslookup whole nine yards. So we undomained restarted, and here we are.

Yes i can ping mydoamin.local and it resolves our DC

Comment: Are any other servers having this issue? Any recent changes (even seemingly unrelated, new hardware/new VM/etc).

Comment: None that i can think of. We haven't really made any changes since xmas break and its been working fine since. Looking in the event log they first error we noticed that MIGHT be the cause is this: "The master browser has received a server announcement from the computer SP-9382 that believes that it is the master browser for the domain on transport NetBT_Tcpip_{00F97306-8E82-4C76-A. The master browser is stopping or an election is being forced."

Comment: Is the netlogon service started?

Comment: `1.` You don't neded to "pre-add" the DNS A record for the server you're joining to the domain. `2.` AD doesn't need or use PTR records so you don't need a PTR record for the server you're joining to the domain. `3.` The master browser maintains the browse list (Network Neighborhood) for the subnet. This is unrelated to your problem. `4.` Run a packet capture on the server in question while trying to join it to the domain. The capture may give you some insight as to what's causing the problem.